# Is there a way to make the generated GUI code from IDEA visible?

Tags: java, user-interface, code-generation, intellij-idea

I have made an extremely simple project in IntelliJ's IDEA, basically just a form with a JToolBar containing a JButton, and when I try to launch it, I get an NPE in form.$$$setupUI$$$ - but no such thing is reflected in the actual form.java, so I have no way to debug it or track down the bug.

Is there a way to make IDEA show (and maybe even let me change) the 'magically' generated code ?

Comment: Just so future readers know: You shall **NOT** change the generated source code! Your changes will be overriden the next time the code is being generated. It also reminds you in the comments that are being generated along with the code. You may track down your problem that way just fine, but then you have to fix it outside of the `$$$setupUI$$$()` method. Screenshot from 14.1.4: http://i.imgur.com/vfD2nD4.png Also, see this, section "Generate GUI Into": https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gui-designer.html http://i.imgur.com/bNcBQ07.png

Answer (score 10):

[Settings | GUI Designer | Generate GUI into | Java source files](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gui-designer.html).

Answer (score 2):

File > Settings > GUI Designer >Generate GUI into Java source code

(see: https://grahamwideman.wikispaces.com/Java+IntelliJ+GUI+app+notes)

Comment: you saved my day. Do you know a maven plugin for that, because I build with maven and cannot used Idea byte weaving, but Idea source code generation spoils git history.

Comment: ideauidesigner-maven-plugin is way to go